# WordPress Database Mail Extract/Harvest

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, email

Does anyone have or can anyone share a link for an SQL query which will allow me to pull all of the email address from the users table of a WordPress database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty straight-forward table (see the official reference [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)):

```
SELECT user_email
FROM   wp_users
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! Suppose it's time I stop asking others and begin learning SQL. Thank you Mureinik!

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 : By using plugin**

If you want to export it CSV file

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-users/

**Case 2 : Database Query**

for all user,

```
SELECT user_email FROM   wp_users
```

for based on conditions,

```
SELECT user_email FROM   wp_users where <condition>
```

**Case 3 : Write into file while register**

```
add_filter( 'register', 'addtoMailCSV' );
function addtoMailCSV(  ) {
 /*Code Want to implement while regsiter*/

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: welcome.last one is very useful its automatic generate list